# Match bibliographic data and remove duplicates even if strings do not match exactly

Tags: r, bibliography, stringdist

I have two sets of bibliographic data. One contains records from PubMed, one from Scopus:

```
data_PubMed <- data.frame(
  Authors = c("AB, CD.", "XX, XY.", "FG, HJ.", "KL, MN.", "OP, QR."),
  Year = c(2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016),
  Title = c("Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5"),
  `Source title` = c("Journal A", "Journal B", "Journal C", "Journal D", "Journal E"),
  DOI = c("DOI1", "DOI2", NA, "DOI4", NA),
  Database = c("PubMed", "PubMed", "PubMed", "PubMed", "PubMed")
)

data_Scopus <- data.frame(
  Authors = c("F.G.; H.J.", "K.L.; M.N.", "O.P.; Q.R.", "S.T.; U.V.", "C.D.; E.F."),
  Year = c(2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014),
  Title = c("Title: 3.", "Title 4", "Title - 5.", "Title 6", "Title 7"),
  `Source title` = c("Journal C", "Journal D", "Journal E", "Journal F", "Journal G"),
  DOI = c(NA, "doi4", "dOi5", NA, NA),
  Database = c("Scopus", "Scopus", "Scopus", "Scopus", "Scopus")
)
```

I want to create a combined data frame which only contains distinct records. In case of a duplicate, I want to retain the record from PubMed, discarding the one from Scopus.

The tricky part is that actual duplicates don't necessarily appear as such due to differently applied conventions when it comes to spelling authors and titles. I tried to reflect these pitfalls in my example code.

So the obvious first choice is to resort to the DOI. Sometimes the same DOI is written lowercase, sometimes uppercase, but this is easy to deal with, using `tolower(DOI)`. So if all records had DOIs, that task would be simple. Just arrange by `$Database` to have "PubMed" first, then `group_by(DOI)` and apply a filter that keeps the PubMed record of each group (DOI):

```
data_Combined <- rbind(data_PubMed, data_Scopus) |>
  mutate(DOI = tolower(DOI)) |>
  arrange(Database) |>
  group_by(DOI) |>
  filter(Database == "PubMed" | (Database == "Scopus" & !any(Database == "PubMed"))) |>
  ungroup()

> data_Combined
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  Authors     Year Title      Source.title DOI   Database
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>        <chr> <chr>   
1 AB, CD.     2020 Title 1    Journal A    doi1  PubMed  
2 XX, XY.     2019 Title 2    Journal B    doi2  PubMed  
3 FG, HJ.     2018 Title 3    Journal C    NA    PubMed  
4 KL, MN.     2017 Title 4    Journal D    doi4  PubMed  
5 OP, QR.     2016 Title 5    Journal E    NA    PubMed  
6 O.P.; Q.R.  2016 Title - 5. Journal E    doi5  Scopus
```

So with my inconsistent data, this approach is obviously wrong for a couple of reasons. "Title 6" and "Title 7" have been eliminated entirely and "Title 5" is actually a duplicate with slight differences that I would have liked to detect.

I know that there is the `stringdist` package that can identify "close enough" strings as matches, but I tried to implement this in my approach to no avail.

Comment: Hi Klaus, there is a lot going on. One way of approaching your problem could be to first filter for all records with DOI and work your "easy" code on this subset. Then you have to handle other cases (with no or incosistent DOIs), etc. This way you do not have to develop a hyper sophisticated query/code. The matched/selected records can be combined with a simply `dplyr::bind_rows()`. The cleaning of strings is inherently difficult. Given your example, you can remove the `dots` in the names, or hyphens from titles. But I guess reality is more complex. Just some initial ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We all strive for neat one-approach-fits-all solutions but yeah, sometimes you have to admit when it's above your paygrade and take the long, scenic route :-) What eliminated quite a few cases was getting rid of all punctuation marks using `gsub("[[:punct:]]")` in conjunction with `tolower()` on the source titles.

Comment: I am with you! And well done. Going in iterations and splitting a problem in smaller sub-problems can be a useful strategy. I find your general problem interesting (as I struggle with a similar issue from time to time) and was googling a bit: this approach might help to handle some of the remaining awkward stuff. I could picture combining this with some initial cleaning (as you did) by removing puntuation, hyphnes, accents, etc and then possibly extracting key nouns for hard cases: https://blog.devgenius.io/approximate-string-matching-in-r-using-jaro-winkler-similarity-a93436ecf38f

Comment: P.S. once done, please post "your" solution as answer. This may help others in the future that end up with this question, if they can follow your implementation/approach.